# iOS browsers not rendering SVG correctly

Tags: html, ios, svg

I have an SVG for Chrome (below), that I am trying to display on iOS Firefox (v25.1), however the SVG is not rendering correctly. Can anyone give me pointers as to what my be causing the issue? Below is the what gets render in Firefox iOS. (Bonus: the rendering it also busted in edge, and after a quick look it looks like it would be busted in safari as well).

[image]

I know the SVG isn't malformed (AFAIK) as I am able to get it render correctly on Desktop Firefox (Windows). 
The SVG also passes SVG 1.1 (and SVG 1.1 Basic) validation.

```html
  <svg width="99" height="98" viewBox="0 0 99 98" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M49.5905 97.4156C76.2285 97.4156 97.823 75.8212 97.823 49.1831C97.823 22.545 76.2285 0.95062 49.5905 0.95062C22.9524 0.95062 1.358 22.545 1.358 49.1831C1.358 75.8212 22.9524 97.4156 49.5905 97.4156Z" fill="white"/>
                <path d="M80.2844 57.9542C80.2844 40.9851 66.5601 27.2608 49.591 27.2608C32.6219 27.2608 18.8976 40.9851 18.8976 57.9542H27.6672C27.6672 45.8522 37.489 36.0303 49.591 36.0303C61.693 36.0303 71.5149 45.8522 71.5149 57.9542" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.1"/>
                <path d="M51.7836 71.9847C60.9858 71.9847 68.4457 64.5248 68.4457 55.3226C68.4457 46.1204 60.9858 38.6605 51.7836 38.6605C42.5813 38.6605 35.1214 46.1204 35.1214 55.3226C35.1214 64.5248 42.5813 71.9847 51.7836 71.9847Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.1"/>
                <path d="M49.5912 67.1613C59.5199 67.1613 67.5687 59.1125 67.5687 49.1838C67.5687 39.2551 59.5199 31.2062 49.5912 31.2062C39.6624 31.2062 31.6136 39.2551 31.6136 49.1838C31.6136 59.1125 39.6624 67.1613 49.5912 67.1613Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
                <path d="M93.4388 27.2605C81.3807 2.96891 51.8712 -6.94067 27.6234 5.16129C20.0377 8.9322 13.5921 14.5886 8.81273 21.5603L28.5442 55.7615C24.9048 44.2296 31.3066 31.9084 42.8824 28.269C44.8994 27.6113 47.0479 27.3044 49.1526 27.2605" fill="url(#paint1_linear)"/>
                <path d="M8.81234 21.559C-6.27127 44.0967 -0.264137 74.6147 22.2736 89.6983C29.2454 94.39 37.3134 97.1963 45.6444 97.854L66.2528 62.7758C58.5356 72.1154 44.7236 73.4308 35.3841 65.7136C32.227 63.0828 29.8592 59.6188 28.5438 55.7602" fill="url(#paint2_linear)"/>
                <path d="M45.6444 97.8556C72.6985 99.9164 96.2885 79.6149 98.3055 52.6047C98.9632 43.8791 97.297 35.1534 93.4384 27.2608H49.1522C61.2542 27.3046 71.0323 37.1704 70.9884 49.2723C70.9446 54.1833 69.3222 58.9188 66.2528 62.7774" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"/>
                <path d="M8.81273 21.5605L28.5442 55.7618C27.0972 50.8508 27.4042 45.5891 29.4212 40.8535L9.68968 20.2451" fill="url(#paint4_linear)"/>
                <path d="M45.6447 97.8558L66.2531 62.7776C63.0084 66.6362 58.492 69.3109 53.5373 70.2317L44.7677 97.8558" fill="url(#paint5_linear)"/>
                <path d="M93.4384 27.2608H49.1523C55.8171 27.3046 62.1312 30.374 66.2529 35.5918L94.3154 28.5762" fill="url(#paint6_linear)"/>
                <defs>
                  <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="49.5843" y1="31.1984" x2="49.5843" y2="67.1535" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#81B4E0"/>
                    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0C5A94"/>
                  </linearGradient>
                  <linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="51.1176" y1="0.064787" x2="51.1176" y2="39.9662" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#F06B59"/>
                    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#DF2227"/>
                  </linearGradient>
                  <linearGradient id="paint2_linear" x1="12.4302" y1="84.0802" x2="32.6001" y2="50.756" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#388B41"/>
                    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#4CB749"/>
                  </linearGradient>
                  <linearGradient id="paint3_linear" x1="79.9989" y1="87.6265" x2="58.5135" y2="35.8862" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#E4B022"/>
                    <stop offset="0.3" stop-color="#FCD209"/>
                  </linearGradient>
                  <linearGradient id="paint4_linear" x1="19.1087" y1="54.4361" x2="19.1087" y2="19.358" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.15"/>
                    <stop offset="0.3" stop-opacity="0.06"/>
                    <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.03"/>
                  </linearGradient>
                  <linearGradient id="paint5_linear" x1="67.5261" y1="65.764" x2="43.4098" y2="90.3187" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.15"/>
                    <stop offset="0.3" stop-opacity="0.06"/>
                    <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.03"/>
                  </linearGradient>
                  <linearGradient id="paint6_linear" x1="67.1766" y1="72.83" x2="70.6844" y2="38.1903" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.15"/>
                    <stop offset="0.3" stop-opacity="0.06"/>
                    <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.03"/>
                  </linearGradient>
                </defs>
              </svg>
```

Comment: All IOS browsers are basically webkit with different skins. I.e. on iOS Firefox isn't really Firefox, it's just the UI, the renderer is Apple's webkit.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yea I discovered that, but the question still stands why doesn't Webkit render the SVG correctly on iOS

Comment: You can report webkit bugs [here](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/)